# Animating from value to another and back on repeat Aframe

Tags: html, animation, aframe

I am new to Aframe and attempting to animate the position of a .glb up and down on a repeating loop but can't quite seem to get it working. Here's what I have.

```
   <!--Text 3D OBJ-->
    <a-entity xrextras-one-finger-rotate gltf-model="#text-glb"  
      rotation="0 0 0" 
      scale="1 1 1"
      animation="property: position; 
                 from: 0 0 0;
                 to: 0 1 0;
                 direction: alternate;
                 dur: 5000; 
                 ease: linear"
       
    ></a-entity>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The direction property is called [dir](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#api_dir) and you need to set [loop](https://aframe.io/docs/1.2.0/components/animation.html#api_loop) to `true`. For instance:

```
<a-sphere 
   animation="property: position;
              from: 0 1.25 -5;
              to: 0 3 -5;
              dir: alternate;
              dur: 1000; 
              ease: linear;
              loop: true"
   radius="1.25" 
   color="#EF2D5E">
</a-sphere>
```

[Runnable example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/prairie-serious-antimatter?path=index.html%3A17%3A58)